# is the subset a subspace...closure properties ???

Tags: linear-algebra

I did a subspace problem here and I got marked wrong for not showing closure properties. What was I supposed to show in this problem ? thanks

[image]

Comment: In general a subset need not be closed.  Take, for example, the subset $\{0,1\}$ of the vector space $\mathbb{R}$.  Certainly it has the zero vector, but is not closed under the vector addition or scalar multiplication.  You need to show these in order to show that a subset $W$ is a subspace, i.e. show that the linear combination of any finite subset of vectors in the given subset also lies in that subset.

Comment: As you've said, "not showing closure properties". This was what you were supposed to show in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show two things to demonstrate (algebraic) closure of the set $W$ in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$:

**I**  $\quad (x,y,z,w), (x',y',z',w') \in W \Longrightarrow (x+x',y+y', z+z', w+w') \in W$.

**II**  $\quad x \in W, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}  \Longrightarrow \alpha x \in W$.

Let's show **I** (then hopefully you can show **II** yourself):

If $ (x,y,z,w), (x',y',z',w') \in W $ then , by defintion of *W*

$$2x + y -3z +6w = 0 $$

and

$$2x' + y' -3z' +6w' = 0. $$

Adding these two equations together gives $$2(x+x') + (y+y') -3(z+z') +6(w+w') = 0. $$

So we see that indeed $(x+x',y+y', z+z', w+w') \in W$ (as this vector satisfies the only condition for membership to $W$).

Comment: wow..thank you...I appreciate it

Comment: That's a pleasure :)